# deploy nginx on azure devtest lab vm

Tags: azure, nginx, virtual-machine

I am new to Azure and I allready have a problem, I am trying to deploy nginx on azure but nothing works !
I created my vm, opened port 22 to connect via ssh and port 80 for the nginx server.
Then I downloaded nginx with apt, I checked it was running but I can never get to the default home page. I tried using the public ip adress and the dns name.
Here is the [network config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/905X3.png)

Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: You need to open port 80 in your Linux VM iptables or in local firewall(firewalld) reference to open ports in Linux https://www.golinuxcloud.com/linux-open-port/

Comment: Hey thx for the reply, if I just deactivate all firewalls it should work right ? It's just for testing purposes... @JayakrishnaGunnam-MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, for those of you that have their firewalls down like me, AND have load balancers direct the traffic to their VM, edit the inbound NAT rules of the load balancers, by adding ports and VM you want your traffic redirecting to, it worked for me.